# How can I set collapseRequests in my buildbot master.cfg

Tags: buildbot

I try to set collapseRequests in my buildbot master.cfg, but when I add

```
c['collapseRequests'] = True
```

Error shows that "**Unknown BuildmasterConfig key collapseRequests**";

When I try to add collapseRequests in BuilderConfig, using

```
c['builders'].append(BuilderConfig(..., collapseRequests=True))
```

Error shows that "**__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'collapseRequests' (traceback in logfile)**"

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are not using a version of Buildbot that supports `collapseRequests`. If I Google for it, I can only find references in the [documentation for the development version of Buildbot](http://docs.buildbot.net/latest/manual/cfg-global.html). If you check that page, you'll see at the top there's a warning that the documentation is for the development version of Buildbot and there's a link to the [documentation of the latest released version](http://docs.buildbot.net/current/).

The latest released version (at the time of writing this answer) is 0.8.12 and does not support `collapseRequests`. What it does support is [`mergeRequests`](http://docs.buildbot.net/0.8.12/manual/cfg-global.html#merging-build-requests).

Comment: Just replace collapseRequests with mergeRequests, everything is fine now. Thanks. :-)